# Does the chance of explosion depend on type of ammunition?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I was playing some games, and I have a feeling that I get ammoracked more frequently when playing vehicles with "Howitzer" guns (tanks with high damage, long reload and bad penetration, mostly firing HE shells, such as the KV-2).

The question is: does the chance of destroying an ammo rack depend on the ammo type? Specifically, do HE and HESH shells have a larger chance of exploding?

Comment: From what I can tell, the type of shell doesn't matter.  It appears the ammo rack has a set amount of health like the rest of the modules of tank.  Once the health is brought to 0, the ammo rack explodes, destroying the tank.  Unless the type of shell changes the amount of health an ammo rack has (which would be odd), then I don't think it matters what shell is in the rack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the type of ammo in the ammo rack does not affect the chance of it exploding. It will always explode as long as ammo is loaded, regardless of the type.

Ammo rack durability varies per tank though, and some tanks have big, easy to hit ammo racks. This means that a tank with a relatively easy to hit ammo rack and low ammo rack durability will have a relatively high chance of ammo rack detonation.

In the case of the KV 2 it has a ammo rack durability of 160, which is low when compared to a tank like the German Tier 6 VK 36.01 (H) which has a durability of 180. In addition the KV 2s ammorack is easy to damage, it's at the rear of the rather big vulnerable turret (the white area in the image below). This combination means that it's ammorack is relatively vulnerable compared to other tanks.

[image: KV 2 damage zones.]

Source: [KV2 tank stats on tanks.gg](http://tanks.gg/tank/kv-2)